# Runtime.exec() to bash javac error

Tags: java, bash

I'm using Runtime.exec() to run a shell script in a Java program. 
The script basically compiles a java program and runs it and goes something like:

```
./run2.sh "/Users/user/Desktop/Test.java" "Test" "/Users/user/Desktop/"
```

my parameters in general are the absolute path of the java file, class name and directory where the supposedly compiled class file is

my script is simply

```
javac "$1"
cd "$3"
java "$2"
```

I've tried running the resulting command in my Terminal and it works fine. however when the java program runs it, I get and error:

```
javac: invalid flag: "/Users/user/Desktop/Test.java"
```

What should I do? I've tried every possible script I can find on the internet (*edit: and I can think of, of course)

(*edit: execute statement)

```
// some code here...
String[] outFile = translate.translate();

try {
    String params = "";
    for(String sss: outFile) {
        String tmp = "\"" + sss + "\"";
        params += tmp + " ";
    }

    String command = "./run2.sh "+params;
    System.out.println(command);

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} //respective catch
```

the first line, `String[] outFile = translate.translate()` returns an array Strings of my supposedly parameters

Comment: how are you running it? Can you paste the exact Runtime.exec() statement?

Comment: Can you show the full output of System.out.println(command);

Comment: fixed. but the output of this code is something like `./run2.sh "<param1>" "<param2>" "<param3>"` which is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is including quote characters in the command string that you are passing to `exec()`.  The `exec()` method does NOT know how to deal with quotes or other "shell language" stuff.  You would be better off trying to execute the command something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{command, arg1, arg2, arg3});
```

where the command and arguments strings DO NOT have quotes around them.

Comment: does it have to be like that or can I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, outFile);`? Where outFile is the array of string arguments I should be passing

Comment: okay, dumb question. I consulted the javadocs and found that that is invalid